# How to pass fixed size messages from one process to another process and viceversa?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, ipc, poco

I need two processes P and Q to communicate via 4KB-long messages. All the messages belong to a session. A session begins with the first message successfully sent by P to Q and finishes when either any of two processes sends a Stop message to the other process or a process terminates. Each process can send and receive a message from the other process. Sending and receiving operations must block until *the whole* message has been sent or received respectively or until a time out occurs, otherwise an error is thrown.

At the moment, my idea is to use a Socket and two queues in shared memory  (one for the messages from P to Q and one for the messages from Q to P). The only purpose of the Socket is to properly implement the session concept I described: it is opened when P sends the first message to Q and is closed when one of two processes wants to deliberately terminate the session (equivalently to the Stop message the described above) or if one of the two  processes terminates for some reasons (this would be done automatically by the OS). In both cases the remaining process can be easily notified of the event. The queues are useful for receiving or sending messages "all at once", as I think there is no easy way to do this via Sockets.

Are there any simpler solutions than the above? I have full access to C++11, boost (e.g. for IPC part) and POCO libraries (e.g. for the appropriate Socket type). Other libraries are not allowed unless they are header-only.

I do NOT care about efficiency.

Comment: It sounds like `boost::interprocess::message_queue` might be what you're looking for. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html The socket implementation is also how many programs work, as it provides the potential for network operation.

Comment: yes, boost message_queue is what I am using atm, but alone does not make my session issue strong and reliable

Comment: What do you mean by "strong" and "reliable"? If you explain why that solution doesn't work it might make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you don't care about efficiency, why is it a problem if the threads wake on partial message send or receive?